# How can I account for users using Task Killers?

Tags: android, variables, global, task

I've made an app and it's pretty stable except when people kill it using Advanced Task Killer and have at least Android 2.2. Android 2.1 and below handle this fine but Android 2.2 and over kill it badly.

All of my global variables are wiped and when the app tries to resume it just breaks.

I know that there is no reason to use a task killer after 2.1, but my customers don't and I'm just wondering if there is any way I can take this into account?

Comment: I am having the same problem - how did you go about rebuilding your app around the problem? I would like my application to go back to the launch activity if it has been killed by a task killer but can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: I basically just put a load of checks in the onResume and onStart methods in each activity and if something detected that objects that were being stored locally have disappeared, then I handled it in the best way possible for my app.

There was no way to recover it so it usually resulted in re-generating what was possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to account for this, so I've re-built my app around it.